# Django 1.11 circular import error, Also url pattern... current path doesn't match

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-urls

I'm using django 1.11.  This is my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 124, in 
inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)

File "C:\Python3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "C:\Python3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
File "C:\Python3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "C:\Python3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
File "C:\Python3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
return check_method()
File "C:\Python3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site- 
packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 255, in check
warnings.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
File "C:\Python3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
return check_method()
File "C:\Python3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site- 
packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 254, in check
for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Python3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\Python3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site- 
packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 414, in url_patterns
raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 
'irbSite.urls' from 'C:\\Users\\doxpr\\Desktop\\WorkingProje
ctClassBased Views\\WorkingProjectClassBased 
Views\\capstoneProject\\capstoneProject\\irbSite\\urls.py'>' does not appear 
to have any p
atterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is 
probably caused by a circular import.
```

As seen above, I'm getting a circular import error when I include:

```
url(r'irbSite/', include('irbSite.urls', namespace = 'irbSite')),
url(r'irbSite/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
```

in urls.py in the project folder:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name = 
        'irbSite/login.html'),name='login'),
    url(r'irbSite/', include('irbSite.urls', namespace = 'irbSite')),
    url(r'irbSite/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
]
```

However, if I do not include it my login page will appear, but when I click the register link I get this error:
"url patterns" ... "^admin/ ^$ [name='login'] The current path, register.html, didn't match any of these."

My directory (not code):

```
irbsite
  pycache
  migrations
  static
  templates
  init.py
  admin.py
  apps.py
  forms.py
  models.py
  tests.py
  urls.py
  views.py
project
  pycache
  init.py
  settings.py
  urls.py
  wsgi.py
manage.py
```

My views.py (in irbSite folder):

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from . import forms

class Registration(CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'register.html'
```

My urls.py (in irbSite folder):

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = 'irbSite'

ulrpatterns = [
    url(r'logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(),name='logout'),
    url(r'register/$',views.Registration.as_view(template_name = 
      'irbSite/register.html'),name='registration'),
]
```

I'm modifying a tutorial that I followed from a udemy course.  I've hit a wall, any advice?

Comment: share more error traceback

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta I just added traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you’re not getting a circular import error, the message just suggests that it might be a circular import causing the problem.

In this case, you have a typo in your `irbSite/urls.py`. It should be `urlpatterns` not `ulrpatterns`.

Comment: Wow.  Thank you.  been looking for days.  when I remove the typo that error is gone, but the other 404 error occurs.

"...Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^$ [name='login']
irbSite/
irbSite/
The current path, register.html, didn't match any of these."

Comment: I should add that the login page loads fine now, but when I click the signup link, it can't find register.html.

Comment: You haven’t defined a url pattern for `register.html`. The url is `/irbSite/register/`.

Comment: If you could forgive my ignorance here, how have I not created a url pattern for register.html?

Comment: A `url()` maps a regex to the view. For example `url(r'register/$', views.Registration.as_view(...), ...)` maps `register/` to the registration view. You haven't defined a url pattern for `register.html`, you defined it for `register/` (and with the `include()` that becomes `/irbSite/register/`). See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/) for more info. This is getting off topic for the original question, so if you're still stuck please ask a new question.

Comment: I would just add that still not sure what you mean here, but the second part of this problem (two part problem as mentioned in question) was resolved due to the tag being {$... instead of {%...  just a typo.  once that was fixed the link to register worked.  thanks for catching the url mispelling, that helped a lot.

Comment: Now that your link is fixed, you’ll see that it takes you to the url `irbSite/register/`. Previously, it took you to `/register.html`, which isn’t a URL in your config. URLs and template filenames are not the same in Django.